# Swift CoreData Failed to call designated initialiser on NSMangedObjectClass

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject

I have 2 classes. My `MainScreenViewController` and my `DataFetch`. In the DataFetch class I have a function [`func loadDesserts(){...}`](https://gist.github.com/foffer/04f92649d2d491eb75f0) where I setup my RestKit and CoreData entity/objectMappings and all the rest.

That function is called from `MainScreenViewController`. But when the class is assigned to a constant: `let dataFetch = DataFetch()` it throws the error:

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class '_TtC9Kogekunst9DataFetch'
```

I've come to the conclusion (although not a 100% certain) that RestKit is not to blame for this problem. I think I'm not initialising the NSManagedObject correctly. I've tried implementing the

```
init(entity entity: NSEntityDescription!,
insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!)
```

But I haven't managed to get it working, as it gives me the same error. The way I tried to implement it was as follows:

```
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = RKObjectManager.sharedManager().managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext
    var entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Dessert", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    let dataFetch = DataFetch(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    dataFetch.loadDesserts()
```

But that throws an 'Fatal - Can't unwrap Optional.none'. So stuck again.

Could someone point me in the right direction as to what to do?

Chris

Comment: Could you able to resolve it

Comment: No, not yet unfortunately, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: hey, Did you able to fix it? Please share so that other can get result.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a Core Data issue and not a problem with RestKit. From the looks of it, the object you are setting either isn't the correct type, i.e., `DataFetch`, or the object is `nil`. Because you can't unwrap an `Optional.none`, you'll have to use a conditional setter:

```
var dataFetch: DataFetch?
var context: NSManagedObjectContext = RKObjectManager.sharedManager().managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext
var entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Dessert", inManagedObjectContext: context)
if let dataFetchObject = DataFetch(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context) as? DataFetch {
    dataFetch = dataFetchObject
    dataFetch.loadDesserts()
}
```

I ran into this issue last night as well, and this is what solved my problem (for now :]).